# What are sufficiency and parameterization invariance in the context of Maximum Likelihood estimation?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, data-mining

While looking at properties of MLE, the articel mentions 4 things below:

1. sufficiency (complete information about the parameter of interest contained in
   its MLE estimator)
2. consistency
3. efficiency
4. parameterization invariance (same MLE solution obtained independent of the 
   parametrization used)

Somehow, I have got the ideas of 2 & 3 but 1 & 4 are not straight to understand.
Hope to hear some explanations about those 1 & 4.